# Polyomino equation part 2

Tags: tiling, polyomino

[image: On the left is a L pentomino. On the right is an T tetromino.]

There is a particular shape (holes are permitted) that you can build with four copies of the piece on the left, or with 5 copies of the piece on the right.  You may rotate and flip the pieces, but they cannot overlap.  What shape can you build?

---

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted. Thank you!**

*EDIT: 48 hours have now passed.  Everyone may post answers now.*

---

<sub>This puzzle is from: http://skepticsplay.blogspot.com/2010/04/polyomino-equations.html</sub>

Comment: I have found an answer, and I'd like to say its quite elegant. Will refrain from posting though.

Comment: Did you know there are actually two solutions ? (not counting reflections/rotations obviously)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the 48 hour mark has gone by, I will post one of the solution(s) I found while merely just playing with the pieces:

> [image]

and subsequently

> [image]

> This was mainly made with the understanding that there probably would have been a hole in the middle of the shape itself, and understanding the shape when 2 T shapes makes one side a tile longer came in itself to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is the second solution. I have used the images from Stevo's solution, and flipped over the bottom-right section.

> [image]
>
>  [image]

I used a computer to find all solutions that fit within a 6x8 rectangle, and they were all equivalent to one of these two solutions.

Comment: Bonus challenge: do solutions exist for any 5 x tetromino paired with a 4 x pentomino? Probably too hard for a puzzle :)

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Solutions are known for [all but two combinations](https://www.iread.it/Poly/P54.html). That site is rather old so maybe the two missing ones have been found by now.

Comment: Oh very cool! Some solutions are large!

Comment: ah this is the polyomino compatibility problem

Comment: even 3 tiles are possible: http://sicherman.net/rosp/triplep.html